# What is the publication number of a patent?

Tags: patent-applications

I'm on the publicpair website and I can't find the publication number for a specific patent I'm researching; is there a place where the pub. number is located, or am I supposed to somehow derive it?

Comment: Please just provide the patent number. That will help get a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm on the publicpair website and I can't find the publication number
>   for a specific patent I'm researching; is there a place where the pub.
>   number is located, or am I supposed to somehow derive it?

Please check the year of application and grant of patent. USPTO started publishing patent application after 2001 if you are looking for patent that has been granted before that you may not find the publication.

Please also check for code **PG.NONPUB.RQ** in image file wrapper of public pair as an applicant can make an application under [35 USC 122](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/35/122) to keep publication confidential.

In addition to the data provided by @George White, the publication number is also available in patent first page

[image]

Comment: I looked at the patent page, but it doesn't have that prior publication data section. Everything else looks just like your example, but after the filed date it jumps straight to related U.S. application data.

Comment: what is the application date? as i have said is patent granted before 2001 then you wont find prior publication.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. The provisional application was filed in 2013.

Comment: I see, thanks so much. The patent in question does indeed have the nonpublication document. Just to clarify, does this mean that there is no publication number for this patent?

Comment: I would be unable to answer that until i have any reference/ document no

Comment: @User provisionals aren't published

Comment: An applicant can check a box to decline publication as long as they do not plan to file anywhere outside the U.S. If publication is selected, there will be no publication.

Answer (score 0):

In the application data tab it is the box labeled "Earliest Publication Number in the right hand column. The format used for these numbers starts with the year of publication.[image: screen shot of the record of a patent application in Public PAIR]

The publication number is US2002/181786A1.

Comment: I looked there, but the patent doesn't have a earliest pub. no.; it's just a -.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments on other answers it looks like it was never published as an application. This can happen due to a [non-publication request](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s1122.html). If no foreign counterpart application will be filed an applicant can request non-publication. Also it could be an old patent as mentioned in another answer. [There were no publications before 2001](https://www.uspto.gov/about-us/news-updates/uspto-will-begin-publishing-patent-applications).

Also a *very* accelerated examination could result in a patent before the publication would have happened. I think that would result in no publication.

Comment: Why did you delete this answer? It is probably the most useful one.

Comment: @EricS  after i posted I realized RishiM answer had most of the same information.